# How to extract data from a list of Urls for web scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I a new to Web scraping and I want to extract the **coordinates** from the `<div>` tag that is accessed through a URL. There is a list of URLs from which I want to extract the coordinates and save them in a CSV file.

```
 <div class="single-view-data-row">
 <div class="single-view-data-title">Coordinates</div>
 <div class="single-view-data-get">
                                 17.009164 N, -90.309259 E<br/><a href="http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/GeoConvert?input=17.009164+-90.309259" target="_blank">»» UTM / MGRS</a></div></div></div>
```

Thanks for the Help!!!

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you mean, you are showing a list of div whearas one contains longitude and latitude together with a link. Do you want the longitude and latitude from the div? But then you mentioned you have successfully extracted the url so I guess you want to webscrape the url inside the longitude/latitude div? Or do you want the `input=17.009164+-90.309259` extracted from the url?

Comment: I scraped the list of URLs and from one of those pages, I got this HTML text. I want the coordinates from every link which is in a div tag and also in a URL.                   
Both would work, whether it be extracting from the URL or from the div tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract link and coordinates from this HTML text, you can use this script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = ''' <div class="single-view-data-row">
 <div class="single-view-data-title">Coordinates</div>
 <div class="single-view-data-get">
                                 17.009164 N, -90.309259 E<br/><a href="http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/GeoConvert?input=17.009164+-90.309259" target="_blank">»» UTM / MGRS</a></div></div></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

link = soup.select_one('.single-view-data-get a')['href']
coords = soup.select_one('.single-view-data-get').find_next(text=True).split(',')

print(link)
print(coords[0].strip())
print(coords[1].strip())
```

Prints:

```
http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/GeoConvert?input=17.009164+-90.309259
17.009164 N
-90.309259 E
```